# Oscilloscopes and Packed Two-Layer PCB boards? (“Operating Table” PCBs)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, oscilloscope, pcb-layers, logic-analyzer

I have recently completed a very complicated 2-layer circuit board. Every square mm has a component in it, two of the sides undergo edge plating, and one is riddled with right-angled connectors.

I would like to use my oscilloscope and logic analyzer to help me debug this circuit, but that will require having somewhere to plug the probes, as the analyzer has two rows of 8 female plug sockets separated by 2.54mm.

[image]
Credit: Rigol Technologies

Notice how the evaluation board that comes with the kit has been set up so that the probe can plug straight onto the pin headers.

Many other development boards I see follow this convention of laying out the design with pin headers connected to relevant nets as well:

[image]
Credit: ST Microelectronics

This setup with pin headers seems user-friendly and I would like to design an “operating table” pcb board which contains the two-layer board that I plan on producing at the center. On the free edge (non-plated and without connectors) another extrusion will jut out that contains rows of pin headers. To connect the headers to the nets, I will add two more layers in the center of the “operating table” pcb that will not be present in the final design. On those layers, I will snag nets from vias passing trough the board and route them to the headers. (Almost) all of my nets pass through the board through vias.

What considerations, aside from the effect of separating the two outer layers a bit (which can be compensated for by changing the board thickness during fabrication), should be taken in laying out such a design? All of my signals are under 20MHz. Should I be concerned about coupling on the inner layers?

Comment: How are the production boards going to be properly tested if you don't allow some means of access to the nodes you need for debugging?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I will have a custom PTC routine to check the board’s end functionality. The output of the board will be measured to verify that it is within acceptable specifications. I will need to test the sub circuits’ general functionality to make such a test possible though.